# Anvil Studio and MidiEditor outputting strange sounds using Casio keyboard

Tags: windows-10, audio, midi

- Trying the freeware, MidiEditor, I was able to record and playback a basic melody using my Casio CTK-2300 keyboard. However, the next day when I tried to play the same midi file on MidiEditor, it played strange sounds out of my keyboard. The file sounds fine when outputting to the Windows built-in MS GS WAVETABLE synth.
- I thought this might be a bug in MidiEditor so I downloaded Anvil Studio, another free midi editor program. Anvil Studio played the same strange sounds when I output to my keyboard.
- It SEEMS that the software programs are assigning the output to unconventional synths on my Casio. For example, instead of outputting to one of the many piano or guitar or melodic instrument synths that are built into the Casio, they seem to be outputting to a combination of buzzes, woodblocks, whistles, and nothings. And it's not even that they seem to be outputting to a single synth, say a percussive synth.
- Why is it doing this? I am guessing that maybe the file on Windows that communicates with or interprets the synths on the Casio is corrupted or subpar in someway, but I'm not sure. I am very ignorant about the subject of sound engineering and digital sound generation, so I'm really just grasping in the dark here. I'm not even sure where to start as far as trying to solve this problem.
- If indeed there is an issue with a particular Windows file, I'm not sure what to do about it. For example, I have found a file called CASIO USB-MIDI.mlb on my harddrive. I do not know where this file came from. I'm not sure if I delete it if Windows will regenerate it so I'm kind of afraid to mess with it.
- If anyone has suggestions on how to solve this problem I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You will probably need to compare the Program Change list on the Casio & GS Wavetable synths; see where they differ & make changes to the file to compensate.

Comment: Thank you. I will do some research on what a Program Change List is and how to work with it. Do you happen to know if most software packages include a way to do a comparison internally? Or would I have to open up the source code somehow in a code editor program?

Comment: Each will have a list published somewhere. Your midi app ought to be able to show you the actual program change data in its editor somewhere. [I know a fair bit about Midi, but I know nothing of any of your hardware or software, I'm afraid, so I've no idea precisely how to access it.]

Comment: Regarding the program change list for the Casio CTK-2300, if you haven't already found it, you'll probably want to have a look at the official appendix [07L5APPEND_WL_1A.pdf](https://support.casio.com/en/manual/008/07L5APPEND_WL_1A_EN.pdf) located [here](https://support.casio.com/en/manual/manualfile.php?cid=008001030). It has Drum Assignment List information as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have configured the keyboard to use one of the drum sets (395­–400).

Try

- powering off the keyboard to reset it; or
- selecting a melodic instrument with the TONE button; or
- adding a GM reset message (`F0 7E 7F 09 01 F7`) at the beginning of the MIDI file.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and report back.